# Django dynamic form thinks it has been posted

Tags: django, django-forms

I've been scratching my head over this one for a couple of hours so now it's your turn :)

I've made a Form that creates its own fields in `__init__`. What/Why it does beside that isn't terribly important so here's a drastically simplified example that still exhibits the same problem:

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, variable, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(args, kwargs)
        for i in range(0, variable):
            self.fields['f_%d' % i] = forms.BooleanField(label="Field %d" % i)

# and in the view:
return render(request, 'survey/form.html', {'f': TestForm(variable=10)})
```

And the template is just `{{f.as_p}}`. The code works ***but*** it also includes error messages. There are 10 errors from each of the BooleanFields saying they're required. But I'm not posting anything and I'm certainly not passing any post data to the TestForm. What you see above is what I'm running (try it yourself).

So what am I doing wrong? Is the form running `is_valid()` and if so why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `__init__` method should be:

```
def __init__(self, variable, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm not sure if that's your problem, or a typo in your question. Your example code means that the form will be initialised with `data=args`.

Comment: I *just* discovered this on my own. Yeah, this wasn't a typo here, I'm just an idiot. Missing expansion asterisks were the problem.